# Create a navbar which can be added/embedded to any site

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a navbar which other sites can simply add/embed on their site.

More specifically, I am working with multiple different website platforms, and I would like to connect the experiences between sites using a shared navbar.

I am hoping to be able to do this through HTML/CSS injection via JavaScript.

I have tried something like this:

```
function addNavBar() {
  // inject css
  let css = document.createElement("link");
  css.rel = "stylesheet";
  css.href = "./navbar.css";
  document.head.append(css);

  // inject html
  var nav_container = document.createElement("div");
  nav_container.id = "my-nav-bar";
  nav_container.innerHTML = navbar_html;
  document.body.prepend(nav_container);
}
```

However, a plan like this fails on full page applications which do numerous tricks to ensure the full screen is filled with their content. Ideally, I would be able to trick the original HTML that the viewport height is 100px less than it is, and simply place my fixed navbar there. Is this possible?

What kind of hacks can enable this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS styles approximating this:

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.navbar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The only issue is, if there are absolute elements in the page (or other elements outside of the regular flow), they won't be affected by the override.